# VBA Excel - Equal dates do not evaluate as equal

Tags: excel, date-comparison, vba

MS Excel Professional Plus v14 on Win7.

I am having trouble comparing equality for date/times.

Two dates that appear to be equal, 12/16/2013 12:19:33 pm are both dimensioned as dates.  One is in a date array, the other is a date variable.  arrPP is ReDim'ed later. When I do DateDiff("s",date1,date2) it yields 0.

```
Dim arrPP() As Date          ' During runtime shows type is Date(1 to 2, 1 to 1)
Dim dNextStartTime as Date

'...code removed ...

    If arrPP(iPP_START, lPP_index) <= dNextStartTime Then
        GoTo PP_OUT
    End If
```

Even though they are equal, the above evaluates to false and the wrong path is taken. This was hard to track down and causes unexpected/wrong results.

Is there an offical "gotcha" regarding date equality?  Are there hidden milliseconds that need to be compared, or a way to limit the comparison down to the seconds level?

I have tried several other alternatives including placing CDate in front of the array element.

FAIL:

```
    If Not(arrPP(iPP_START, lPP_index) > dNextStartTime) Then
        GoTo PP_OUT
    End If
```

PASS:  (But who would think to do this?)

```
    If arrPP(iPP_START, lPP_index) <= dNextStartTime Or _
       DateDiff("s",arrPP(iPP_START,lPP_index),dNextStartTime) = 0 Then
        GoTo PP_OUT
    End If
```

Comment: `VBA Excel - Equal dates do not evaluate as equal` How are you populating the dates? It works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to floating point precission issues.  Dates are stored as double precission floats, where the integer part is date and fractional part is time.

To test if `arrPP(iPP_START,lPP_index)` is before `dNextStartTime` it's probably best to use

```
If DateDiff("s",dNextStartTime,arrPP(iPP_START,lPP_index)) <= 0 Then
```

Note that `DateDiff` returns possitive when the first date parameter is earlier than the second.

To demonstrate how two apparently equal dates may not be equal, try running this

```
Sub demo()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date

    d1 = #12/17/1986 12:19:33 PM#

    d2 = #12/17/1986#
    d2 = d2 + 12# / 24#             ' Add 12 hour
    d2 = d2 + 19# / 60# / 24#       ' Add 19 minutes
    d2 = d2 + 33# / 60# / 60# / 24# ' Add 33 seconds

    Debug.Print d1; d2
    Debug.Print d1 = d2
    Debug.Print d1 - d2
End Sub
```

Immediate window output

> 17/12/1986 12:19:33 p.m. 17/12/1986 12:19:33 p.m.
>   False
>   3.63797880709171E-12

Comment: Hmm.  It's interesting that DateDiff() comes to 0 but  a = b comes out false. Maybe DateDiff() is built to handle the imprecision?  It seems like that would cause people a lot of problems!

Comment: `DateDiff` calculates the difference to the resolution specified (seconds in this case)  The example I just added shows a difference due to floating precission of ~0.3 microseconds

Comment: Bottom line, comparing floating point values for equality (no matter what they represent) is a bad idea

Comment: Guess I'll be switching just about all of my date comparisons to DateDiff(). Thanks!

Comment: + 1 Nice example. BTW try your code with `#1/1/2001 12:19:33 PM#` ;)

Comment: Thanks @sid.  Many dates _do_ work, but that's not the point.  The fact is some don't, which makes test for equality unreliable.  I had to go searching for an example that doesn't work, hence the '86 date!

Comment: Ah! I was wondering how did you come up up with that specific example LOL

Comment: I even tried DateAdd() to add the hrs, min and seconds but got the same result as you.

Answer (score 1):

> VBA Excel - Equal dates do not evaluate as equal

It works for me.

I guess it boils down to how are you storing the date in the date variable or the date array. How are you populating the dates?

Here is the test that I did. Let me know if I have misunderstood your query.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim MyAr(1, 1) As Date

    dt = #12/16/2013 12:19:33 PM#
    MyAr(1, 1) = #12/16/2013 12:19:33 PM#

    If (MyAr(1, 1) > dt) Then
        MsgBox "MyAr is greater"
    ElseIf (MyAr(1, 1) < dt) Then
        MsgBox "MyAr is lesser"
    Else
        MsgBox "They are equal" '<~~ This is what I get
        Debug.Print DateDiff("s", MyAr(1, 1), dt)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your example works for me, too, even when I change the first condition to If (MyAr(1,1) = dt).  It evaluates to true.  It also works if I put the date in cell $A$1 and read it from there. My arrPP is populated by reading date-formatted cells in my worksheet. The dates in those cells look normal.  dNextStartTime is initialized to "12:00" and is usually reset to a date read from the worksheet in a date-formatted cell (looks normal). dNextStartTime might be reset again from a date in a variant array, but then I use dNextStartTime = CDate(arrOther(x,y)).  Equality important for scheduling app.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't need an answer after so many years but if anybody will join this question maybe it will be useful.

```
Function DateEqual(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Boolean
    'use should never compare as equal dates or any double values but if you really need to do it carefully use this function.
    'converting to integers to test if they are equal. if you need to test time values recorded with less then 1second DO NOT USE THIS FUNCTION.
    Dim day1, day2 As Date
    Dim time1, time2 As Date
    day1 = Int(date1)
    day2 = Int(date2)
    If day1 = day2 Then
        If Hour(date1) = Hour(date2) And Minute(date1) = Minute(date2) And Second(date1) = Second(date2) Then
            DateEqual = True: Exit Function
        Else
            DateEqual = False: Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        DateEqual = False: Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```